# С setlocale выводит крокозябры, а с SetConsoleCP все нормально

Tags: c++

вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU");
    string s1;
    getline(cin,s1);
    if (s1.size() != 5)cout << "В слове не 5 букв";
    else cout << s1[4] << s1[3] << s1[2] << s1[1] << s1[0];
}
```

вводишь слово из пяти букв выводятся крокозябры

а вот так все нормально:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string s1;
    getline(cin,s1);
    if (s1.size() != 5)cout << "В слове не 5 букв";
    else cout << s1[4] << s1[3] << s1[2] << s1[1] << s1[0];
}
```

почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1):

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU");` влияет на (стандартные виндовые) программы и функции, которые меняют своё поведение в зависимости от локали.

`SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` меняет кодировку символов в твоём консольном окне

Короче, ничего общего.

Comment: так почему оба способы добавляют русский язык, но результат отличается

Comment: Первый способ добавляет параметры русской локали (т.е., системных настроек форматов даты, денег, алфавитной сортировки).  Второй способ настраивает кодовую страницу твоего экземпляра консольного окна (для русского языка таких кодовых страниц - несколько, и 1251 - вовсе не дефолтная, откуда и твоя проблема).  Есть ещё отдельная настройка кодовой страницы для параметров WinAPI-функций (чтобы открыть файл с русскими буквами в имени) и отдельная настройка для языка интерфейса ОС.  И вот все вместе они "добавляют русский язык" )))